# How to store websocket session in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, websocket

I am creating a demo in which the task is to push a Notifications to clients.
For the same I am using `java websockets` and `MongoDB`.
For pushing notifications to particular client I need to store some  information of the same client. Primarily I am storing the client information as below collection,

```
{
    "id" : "client1",
    "uri" : "ws://testUri",
    "gcmRegId" : "testGcmId",
    "sessions" : []
}
```

I am confused how to store the *websocket session* in database, so whenever I have to notification for *client1* I will just retrieve the corresponding session from database and will push notification through the same session.

Comment: Why would you persist websocket sessions to the database? As long as the connection is open, the Java server needs to be aware of them, so it will have them in memory. When the connections are closed, they are no longer valid and a new session needs to be created.

Comment: hey @Philipp , yes, this was one of the option. But currently I am getting notification request somewhat like **sendNotification(clientId, Notification)**, so my idea was to fetch only open sessions of corresponding _clientId_ 
and push notifications to only those sessions. And if some session get closed remove it from DB also. To change idea as per your sugesstion I will have set session parameter for _clientId_ and whenever there is a notification for some _clientId_ I will have to scan all available sessions for the same _clientId_, which could be time consuming

Comment: @RavindraThoat You can use a [java.util.WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) to map clientId's to existing sessions.